# Idiom for default initialization depending on type

Tags: c++11, default-value, member-variables

I have a template class that takes default member values.

```
template<class T = std::string>
struct A{
    T val = {"val"};
};
```

However sometimes the default values do not make sense, for example:

```
A<int> a1;  // cannot initialize int from "val"
```

**Is there is good idiom to handle this issue?**

I came up with this solution, which is quite verbose.

```
template<class T, class TT>
auto valid_or_default(TT&& other) -> 
decltype(T{std::forward<TT>(other)}){return T{std::forward<TT>(other)};}

template<class T>
auto value_of_default(...){return T{};}

template<class T = std::string>
struct A{
    T val = valid_or_default<T>("val");
};
```

(The other option is to set up a Boost.Fusion map to have a default value per type, but it is even more code and all the cases need to be handled.)

---

**Update** (thanks @Someprogrammerdude):
Another alternative for very specific cases (no valid based on syntax) can be done by specializing the constructor:

```
template<class T = std::string>
struct A{
    T val;// = valid_or_default<T>("val");
    A() : val{}{}
};

template<> A<std::string>::A() : val{"val"}{}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want templates for this? Could it be solved through *specialization*? And what is the *actual* problem you need to solve? *Why* do you initialize a templated member variable with a fixed value?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, specializing member variable initialziation is doesn't seem to be a feature of the language: `template<>
std::string A<std::string>::val = "val";` gives `val is not a static member`. I could specialize the whole class (trying to avoid that).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, you are right, I can specialize the default constructor, but it is still not as powerful. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

I still don't know what the original problem you try to solve is, or why you need to use a compile-time fixed-value for the initialization, but as it seems your structure is an *aggregate* you could simply use [*aggregate initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization):

```
template<typename T = std::string>
struct A
{
    T val;
};

// ...

A a = { "val" };
A<int> b = { 1 };
```

Comment: Well, the idea is to use in generic code, `template<class T> f(){A<T> a; ... }`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a C++17 solution:

```
template<class T, class TT>
auto valid_or_default(TT&& other)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_constructible_v<T, TT>)
        return T{std::forward<TT>(other)};
    else
        return T{};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option.

```
template <typename T>
T get_default_value()
{
   return {};
}

template <> 
std::string get_default_value<std::string>()
{
   return "val";
}

template<class T = std::string>
struct A {
    T val = get_default_value<T>();
};
```